# How do I select text from terminal by using keyboard only?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, gnome-terminal, clipboard

I used to select text via mouse click+drag but I want to know if I can do the same thing via the keyboard only?

I am talking about selecting text with the help of the keyboard on `gnome-terminal`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If you use Urxvt, you can extend the keyboard functionality of the terminal using [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls), a collection of scripts that enables:

- selecting text
- passing URLs to your $browser
- searching your scrollback
- and yanking and pasting to and from your clipboard

Essentially, with urxvt-perls installed, you can dispense with your mouse entirely.

Comment: This answer lacks of an explanation on how to actually _use_ these tools.

Comment: Here is a great video of how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaBf_yFHps8&feature=youtu.be&t=505

The [urxvt-pearls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls) repo has instructions for how to set it up.

Comment: The  urxvt-perls repo has been archived.

Answer (score 6):

For GNOME Terminal 3.30.1 in Ubuntu 18.10: use "find" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>), enable regular expressions and search for a regular expression covering the range of text you wish to select.  Once you have it, you can close the "Find" window by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and copy your text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your terminal.  If this is something important to you, you could consider Emacs `term-mode` which gives you the full text-manipulation capability of the editing environment.  It's possible that you consider that to be overkill, of course!

Answer (score 1):

You could use neovim and [nvim_terminal_emulator](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html)

> Nvim embeds a VT220/xterm terminal emulator based on libvterm. The
>   terminal is presented as a special buffer type, asynchronously updated
>   from the virtual terminal as data is received from the program
>   connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to [*xterm dump of full scrollable window content*](//stackoverflow.com/q/29987557) make it sound like you *could* write your own application to do it. When you invoke the application from a terminal, it would let you use (readline-like) keystrokes to move a visible selected area around the terminal. Finally, press a key to exit, leaving the current highlight as your selection.

Allowing your application to know the content of the terminal is tricky. The link above mentions several possible ways to do it. I'm most beguiled by the idea of using `script` to do it. Perhaps on install, your application would need a script invocation added to `.bashrc`, so that all interactive terminals capture their content to a file. Then when invoked, use the correct one of those files to determine the content of its parent terminal.

This sounds really fiddly to get right. Your application would have to invisibly render the stream to a 2D array, to figure out what the terminal currently looks like. As part of that, it would have to account for newlines and tabs, obviously, and for zero-width characters such as changing colors, and understand all the control characters such as "position cursor".

On the upside, it might work anywhere 'script' could be run, so long as the terminal supports ANSI, which is about all of them apart from the old Windows "cmd.exe".