# How do you use the keyboard to highlight the text you want to copy in konsole?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, konsole

When I want to copy and paste text from the `konsole` screen I have to use the mouse but I find that rather awkward.

Is there a way to enter a mode where you can use the keys to highlight the text you want to copy? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> can be used to copy at that state but it is the initial highlighting I want to use the keys for.

Comment: This has already been asked mutliple times: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210768/how-do-i-select-text-from-terminal-by-using-keyboard-only https://askubuntu.com/questions/55162/shortcuts-to-select-text-in-terminal

Comment: @BlueManCZ I've seen similar questions, but my question is specifically  for KDE's `konsole`

Comment: I understand. Hope somebody will help you. If not, you can still try the `screen` trick.

Comment: you can use termit it can serve your purpose i think.
hope it help.
https://github.com/thestinger/termite.git